# Very Strange CPU Usage with PHP-FPM/MYSQL/NGINX

Tags: nginx, mysql, php, cpu-usage, ioncube

I have

- php-fpm 7.0.11 - with ioncube
- nginx 1.10.x
- mariadb 10.1

I'm using the PHP-FPM to static, I never had any problems with this. The High CPU usage occurred randomly, and now it's permanent. I didn't make any changes.

At the time we are talking the CPU usage is at 100% with most of the PHP-FPM processes in R state.

Here is a top output
My CPU is 16 threads

```
top - 08:21:15 up 31 min,  2 users,  load average: 799.18, 782.54, 620.78
Tasks: 1082 total, 799 running, 283 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 98.5 us,  1.3 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0
```

My webserver is getting more than 5000 requests / second but with this amount everything was fine before.

Is very strange because:

- If i replace the ioncubed , with the original source of PHP file, the load is decreasing to 8 , as well as the cpu usage to only 15-20%
- If i KEEP the ioncube, but stop the mysql, the load average and cpu is decreasing too.
- Sometimes when i change the sysctl config, the cpu is decreasing for 10 seconds but then again it goes 100%

I can't explain this, because if it was the ioncube, i would have the problem with the 2) but i don't.

I really have lost my hair trying to find the real cause of it and it makes me crazy because that happened when i didn't change anything.

My sysctl file is as follow:

```
net.core.wmem_max= 1677721600
net.core.rmem_max= 1677721600
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem= 1024000 8738000 1677721600
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem= 1024000 8738000 1677721600
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 8000
net.ipv4.route.flush=1
fs.file-max=265536
net.core.somaxconn = 65535
vm.max_map_count=655300
```

Comment: Please post your www.conf file.

Comment: The bug is on IonCube. I contacted them. There was a line, that for some reason caused problem on Ioncube encoded files, but with source files it was OK. It didn't happen when i was closing mysql, because that line was AFTER mysql connection.